# can we import the specified classes jar file from another mincroanut project to an micronaut project

Tags: groovy, micronaut

I have 2 micronaut  (groovy ) projects , called project **A** and project **B**

Project **B** has controllers and services ( package com.service , com.controller )
but I only created jar from package com.service
the code in com.service package has **@Singleton** annotation and **@Scheduled**

and I has enabled annotation processing as link (https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#ideaSetup) to both projects
please see my gradle code below to generate JAR file ( the output file is project-b-libs-0.x.jar)

```
task createLibraryJar(type: Jar) {
    baseName( getArchivesBaseName() + "-libs")
    from sourceSets.main.output
    includeEmptyDirs = false
    include '**/service/**/*.class'
}
```

Then I added proejct-b-libs-0.x.jar to Project A
The gradle's dependencies are below

```
dependencies {
annotationProcessor "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-java"
implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-validation")
implementation("io.micronaut.groovy:micronaut-runtime-groovy")
implementation("javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api")
implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client")
runtimeOnly("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic")
compileOnly files('libs/project-b-libs-0.4.jar')
compile "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject"
}
```

Finally after I tried  call **@Inject** Object from the class in JAR file, it showed error on run time

> Caused by: io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanContextException: Error
> loading bean [com.service.TestService]:
> com/service/StripePaymentService

Project A has com.service.TestService to call com.service.StripePaymentService which is in JAR file

Sorry for my English and Thank you to trying to understand me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
compile files('libs/project-b-libs-0.4.jar')
```

I just use compile , not compileOnly , and can not use jar file from gralde script above when I extract jar file , some mincronaut's stuff is missing

so I try another gradle task's script as below ( change from include to exclude )

```
task createLibraryJar(type: Jar) {

    baseName( getArchivesBaseName() + "-libs")
    from sourceSets.main.output
    includeEmptyDirs = false
    exclude '**/controller/**/*.class'

}
```

and it works because the micronaut's stuff still in JAR file, I only exclude unnecessary classes from my jar file